# Mlab - mongoDb mongoose sort by date

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mlab

I have the data stored like following in mlab

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "576c89c00662d4e4a548728f"
    },
    "createddate": {
        "$date": "2016-06-24T01:15:44.362Z"
    },
    "_idapt": "5754cec6dcba0f2aab5c0bca",
    "originalname": "Jan.JPG",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to sort based on createddate

I tridd the following but it doesn't work

```
Files.find({_idapt:req.params._idapt},{sort:{createddate: 1}}, function(err, task) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
```

Any idea how to sort this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try any one

```
Files.find({_idapt:req.params._idapt}).sort({createddate: 1}).exec(function(err, tasks) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
    return res.status(200).send(tasks);
});
```

**OR**

```
Files.find({_idapt:req.params._idapt}, null, {sort: {createddate: 1}}, function(err, tasks) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
    return res.status(200).send(tasks);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:-

You have to use `cursor.sort()` [see odc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/).

```
Files.find({_idapt:req.params._idapt}).sort({'createddate.$date': 1}).toArray(function(err, task) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json(task); //This will be an array of objects
});
```